# Автоматическое создание style guide для сайта

Tags: javascript, scss, style-guide

Мудрые люди подскажите пожалуйста, что лучше использовать для автоматизированного создания style guide из комментариев в scss

Буду очень признательна

**UPD**

Пример комментариев:

```
// A button suitable for giving a star to someone. 
// :hover - Subtle hover highlight. 
// .star-given - A highlight indicating you've already given a star. 
// .star-given:hover - Subtle hover highlight on top of star-given styling. 
// .disabled - Dims the button to indicate it cannot be used.
```

Comment: опишите немного подробнее. и добавьте, плз, пример комментария и что в итоге хочется получить. ( PS: разве комментарии в SCSS не игнорируются при компилировании в CSS ) ( PPS: прошу прощения, если я вне контекста )

Comment: // A button suitable for giving a star to someone.
//
// :hover             - Subtle hover highlight.
// .star-given        - A highlight indicating you've already given a star.
// .star-given:hover  - Subtle hover highlight on top of star-given styling.
// .disabled          - Dims the button to indicate it cannot be used.

Comment: как вариант комментария а складываться должно все в файлик  html

Comment: Что то вроде такого https://github.com/SC5/sc5-styleguide

Comment: @ЮлияЗайцева дак вы не плохую систему в пример привели, почему бы её не использовать?)

Answer (score 1):

Предполагаю, что отличным вариантом станет инструмент [KSS](http://warpspire.com/kss/), пример комментариев вы сами и привели, и который работает с SCSS.

Собственно, пример комментариев с кодом:

```scss
// A button suitable for giving stars to someone.
//
// :hover             - Subtle hover highlight.
// .stars-given       - A highlight indicating you’ve already given a star.
// .stars-given:hover - Subtle hover highlight on top of stars-given styling.
// .disabled          - Dims the button to indicate it cannot be used.
//
// Styleguide 2.1.3.
a.button.star{
  …
  &.star-given{
    …
  }
  &.disabled{
    …
  }
}
```

И пример генерируемой доки - http://primercss.io/buttons/

P.S. Все примеры с оффсайта.